# Using Slack SCIM API to provision users via SailPoint IIQ

Tags: slack-api, scim, sailpoint

I want to use SailPoint IIQ to provision and de-provision Slack users via Slack SCIM API. Slack SCIM API uses version 1.1. and uses Basic or OAuth for authentication. 
I have setup a Slack Enterprise account, generated the API key, and the SCIM API call works via Postman or cURL. However, I am unable to setup the Basic Auth or OAuth tokens for authentication.
Please help!

Answer (score 1):

Am missing quite a bit of information to help direct you - but lets hit on commonly missed settings:

Setting Basic Auth and OAuth tokens can be done via the application "Web Services" - in 7.3 the connector was greatly improved for connecting to API's. Under the configuration section of the newly created application you can find all the settings you are refering to above.

[image]

For provisioning an account for the SCIM 1.1 Service provider such as Slack and Salesforce, in the body of the POST, set form-data values as follows:

Key: connector_skipSchemaAttributes,
Value examples are: alias, costCenter, x509Certificates, ims

Key: connector_extensionSchemaAttributes
Value example: urn:scim:schemas:extension:enterprise:manager

Answer (score 0):

In Postman, you'll have use that Slack token as a bearer token to make it work.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. You should not post just an image as your answer. You should type out an explanation of the steps required to do what your image is showing.